# Iterating through a GridView to find a row's binded text

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I need to iterate through a GridView and find the value of the `Eval("name")` column of each selected row.

Code:

```
string title = "";
foreach (GridViewRow row in gdv.Rows)
{
    if (row.BackColor.Equals(Color.LightGoldenrodYellow))
    {
        title += row.Cells[0].Text + ", "; // doesn't work, even though the value i want is in the very first column
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your complete code, so that we can better understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way (use your control and ID):

```
    foreach (GridViewRow Row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        Label MyLabel = Row.FindControl("Label1") as Label;

        if (MyLabel != null)
        {
            Response.Write(MyLabel.Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: it's not a label. there isn't a control in the cell, just Eval